# Xamarin: Block sleep mode while running a process

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Sometimes it is required to turn off sleep mode in the application while a lengthy process is running. When the process has done, sleep mode can be turned on again.

How to do that in Xamarin, for Android and iOS projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll make an interface and use DependencyService to run platform-specific implementation in the platform-agnostic project.

In the platform agnostic project create an interface:

```cs
namespace MyCompany.Services {
    public interface ISleepModeHandler
    {
        public void BlockSleepMode(bool blockSleepMode);
    }
}
```

In the Android project:

1. In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add this permission:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

2. Add Xamarin.Essentials dependency to the platform-agnostic and to the android project. And don't forget to [initialize Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Candroid) in the android project.
3. Create the class:

```cs
using Android.Views;
using MyCompany.Android.Services;
using MyCompany.Services
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
    
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SleepModeHandlerForDroid))]
namespace MyCompany.Android.Services
{
    public class SleepModeHandlerForDroid : ISleepModeHandler
    {
        public void BlockSleepMode(bool blockSleepMode)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
            { 
                MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)Platform.CurrentActivity;

                if (blockSleepMode)
                {
                    activity.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
                }
                else
                {
                    activity.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

4. In iOS project create the class:

```cs
using MyCompany.Services;
using MyCompany.iOS.Services;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SleepModeHandlerForiOS))]
namespace MyCompany.iOS.Services
{
    [Foundation.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class SleepModeHandlerForiOS : ISleepModeHandler
    {
        public void BlockSleepMode(bool blockSleepMode)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = blockSleepMode;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. Now, in platform agnostic module, when you want to block sleep mode while processing, and turn it on afterwards use the following approach:

```cs
ISleepModeHandler sleepModeHandler = DependencyService.Get<ISleepModeHandler>();
sleepModeHandler.BlockSleepMode(true); // blocking the sleep mode

// your process goes here

sleepModeHandler.BlockSleepMode(false); // allowing the sleep mode again
```